# UITextField - how do i use a custom keyboard and disable the default keypad

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uitextfield

I am using a UITextField to get input for a price field. Since it is for price, I wanted to make a custom keyboard for just a numpad and a decimal button. I have the keypad view setup, however, I dont' know how to disable the default iphone keyboard completely. Any ideas?

Comment: you can change the textFields input view simply as, 

[textField setInputView: <customView>]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass `UITextField` and override `canBecomeFirstResponder`. Return NO and it will never put up a keyboard. However, you'll need to be in charge of handling touches so you can enable/disable your own keyboard. This may affect cut/copy/paste behavior so think about whether you really want to do this.

Comment: thanks for the idea, I came up with an alternative solution. I made a uitextfield and disabled the "user interaction". Then i created an invisible custom button on top of the uitextfield that targets a function that launches the keyboard.

Comment: I have followup question now. Is there a way to enable the cursor even after disabling "user interaction"?

Answer (score 3):

```
[yourTextField setInputView:yourKeyPadView];
```

Comment: the new decimal pad keyboard available in the latest iOS releases could be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in the Interface Builder:

[image: Number pad2]

[image: Number pad2]

**Choose Numbers and Punctuation**